# Testrigor - Logs for developers

Tags: testrigor

Could you please let us know if we have Browser Logs in TestRigor so that developers could find where and what is wrong in the code.  If we have it, could you please give us details as to how to get to it.

Comment: It looks like testrigor doesn't have this feature yet

Answer (score 0):

To access console logs for each step click on "More details..." and click on "console.log" link.

[image]